# Which Goggles are best alternatives for Digital FPV Systems?

Tags: dji, fpv-goggles

I don't want to buy DJI Goggles, because it's too expensive and I'm a beginner, so I've been searching for the best alternatives, I am planning to buy DJI Air Unit and Radiomaster controller and custom built drone, but couldn't find best goggles.

So can you guys suggest some of the best goggles with digital compatibility?

Comment: DJI's business model is quite similar to apple's. Buy all of their gear, or buy none of their gear. Fatsharks' sharkbyte system is a competing digital system, but it is not compatible with DJI's air unit. Whether you agree with this business model is another discussion, but there's no competing goggle that works with the DJI air unit

Comment: Thanks @BrydonGibson, Caddx has digital system but that also doesn't support any other goggles with HDMI input?

Comment: The caddx digital air units are made for the dji fpv system. DJI appears to have licensed out the protocol, but they are still very proprietary

Answer (score 7):

To use a DJI air unit, you must have the DJI goggles, period.

Fatshark's Shark Byte system is a cheaper alternative for digital fpv. Shark Byte works with any goggle that will take hdmi input. If your goggles are not fatshark though, you may have to figure out your own way to mount the receiver to the goggles.

Ultimately, analog is still the cheapest way to get started.

Comment: Thanks, Caddx digital system also doesn't support any other goggles with HDMI input?

Comment: @KashifAnwaar The Caddx digital camera is designed to work with DJI, they have a licensing agreement. And the DJI hardware only works with the DJI goggles. The only alternative to DJI for digital is shark byte (that I'm aware of), and caddx doesn't have a shark byte camera. In theory, anyone can make a shark byte camera though, so maybe they will in the future.

Answer (score 0):

While several alternatives to drone goggles exist, it's crucial to acknowledge that none of these options provide the immersive experience and safety that drone goggles deliver. [Here are the alternatives to drone goggles](https://theeazyshop.com/can-you-fly-fpv-drone-without-goggles/?preview=true#Are_there_alternatives_to_drone_goggles).

Answer (score 0):

You need DJI goggles to use the DJI air unit (or the Caddx Vista/Runcam Link). The digital stuff is all proprietary.

If you don't want to buy a digital FPV system, I'd recommend going with the cheapest set of box goggles you can find. These are about \$50 with an analogue camera and VTX being about another \$50. It's not a bad idea to start with analogue gear, in case you lose the drone entirely or otherwise damage it.

Box goggles are a bit chunky to transport and wear, but the picture quality is pretty similar to much more expensive goggles. It doesn't really matter how good the screen is when the input signal is low-quality.

Most importantly, once you see the view through digital HD goggles, you will want to start saving for it. The record in our club is under a week from trying it to buying it.

One way to save money is to buy second hand DJI goggles. Now the third version has been released, some people are selling their earlier versions.

Comment: Yeah, used DJI goggles are the closest thing.